# Table layout shrinked in tablet in Android

Tags: android, tablelayout

I have made an application that runs on Samsung Galaxy 2S. I am extending it to tablet so I have copied all the layouts and pasted in the layout-large folder.

Problems occurred with image shifting and size. I have solved them, but in the layout, where I used a table layout it shrinked. Can you please tell me whether this is a problem of images or of the layout design?

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:shrinkColumns="*"
    android:stretchColumns="*" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow00"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView00"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:text="ORGANIZER"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText01"
            android:textColor="#000000"
             android:textSize="16dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="ORGANIZER FILLL"
             android:background="@drawable/text_field_1"
            android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
            android:inputType="text" />
    </TableRow>



    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
             android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="AGENDA"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <EditText
            android:textColor="#000000"
             android:background="@drawable/text_field_1"
           android:textSize="16dp"
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="AGENDA FILL"
            android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
            android:inputType="text" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:gravity="center"
             android:textSize="20dp"
            android:text="DETAILS"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <EditText
            android:textColor="#000000"
             android:background="@drawable/text_field_1"
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_span="2"
             android:textSize="16dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="DETAIL FILL"
            android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences"
            android:text="" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_span="2"
             android:textSize="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="WHERE"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <EditText
             android:background="@drawable/text_field_1"
            android:id="@+id/editText3"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_span="2"
             android:textSize="16dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="WHERE FILL"
            android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
            android:inputType="textCapWords" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:gravity="center"
             android:textSize="20dp"
            android:text="TIME"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <EditText
            android:textColor="#000000"
             android:background="@drawable/text_field_1"
            android:id="@+id/editText6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_span="2"
             android:textSize="16dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="TIME FILL"
            android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
            android:inputType="time"
            android:text="" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow9"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_span="2"
             android:textSize="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="DATE"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <EditText
             android:background="@drawable/text_field_1"
            android:id="@+id/editText4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:gravity="center"
             android:textSize="16dp"
            android:hint="DATE FILL"
            android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
            android:inputType="date"
            android:text="" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="INVITE"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <EditText
            android:textColor="#000000"
             android:background="@drawable/text_field_1"
            android:id="@+id/editText5"
             android:textSize="16dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="INVITE FILL"
            android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
            android:inputType="textCapWords" />
    </TableRow>



    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow17"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="EDIT"

            android:visibility="visible" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="UPDATE"
            android:textColor="#000000"
          />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try making your each tablerow as below...

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow01"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
```

I guess `wrap_content` is causing this shrink...